# how to find xml query in bi_publisher

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, bi-publisher

I create a **data_model** in **Bi_Publisher** and set it to my **RTF_template** report.

**the question is** : how to find the query in database when I running my report?

mean:
I want to find the query that Database executing , not query in my data_model.
( or I want the query behind of report)

the query behind report:

```
select /* QUERY_SRC('datamodel: __weblogic_PYN_QSN_ACT_IND_IND_NEW_xdm,dataset:Person_IN') */ from P_crm.vw_person where id  = 1 *
```

Database, how to find relation between data sets in bi_publisher?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running in an Oracle database, you can use v$sql.

```
select * from v$sql
```

Details on that here: 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2113.htm#REFRN30246

Comment: yea I know. but BI_Publisher send some query with hint that I don't know how to work it

Answer (score 0):

All the SQLs being run can be seen in the logs. Increase the logging level on OBIEE, and this will generate detailed logs, containing the presentation logs, but also detailed , performance improved logs running on the database. Its a bit hard to read, but you can search with the table names, if you know them.

There are some instructions [here](http://mkashu.blogspot.com/2017/03/examine-query-log-in-obiee-12c.html)